# Time Complexity of Binary Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

As far as I know, Integer Linear Programming(ILP) problem is NP-complete.
According to the following paper, Binary Linear Programming problem(BLP) can be solved in Polynomial time.
http://dx.doi.org/10.4236/ajor.2016.61001

I'm not familiar with the convex Quadratic Problem mentioned in the paper. However, I know that ILP can be converted to Binary Linear Programming problem in polynomial time, which means ILP will also be P, rather than NP-complete, if this paper is correct.

If the paper above is something rubbish, then for the following specific BLP problem, can it be solved in polynomial time of n? *The very special point of this BLP is that **the coefficients $A$** are also **binary**.*

\begin{align} 
\min_{x} \quad & [c]_{1 \times n}[x]_{n \times 1} \\ 
\text{s.t.} \quad & [A]_{m \times n}[x]_{n \times 1} = [1]_{m \times 1} \\ 
\; & x\in\mathbb{B}\\
\; & A\in\mathbb{B}\\
\; & \forall j\in\{1,2,...,n\}, \sum\limits _{i=1} ^m A_{i,j} =k;k\in Int^+
\end{align}

I strongly believe this problem can be solved in Polynomial time, as I've tried "bintprog"(Tomlab/CPLEX) in Matlab on this problem of size up to n≈14000, and it can be solved in 5s on my laptop(intel i5-4210U). I've done some search in the IBM CPLEX document, but still haven't got a clue yet.

Right now I can only confirm the time complexity of this problem as $ O(n^m)$, but this is not a strong Polynomial Time notation as $ m $ can be as large as $ n $.

Comment: BLP is NP-complete, so I wouldn’t trust the paper. Your special case is NP-complete, by reduction from 1-in-3 SAT.

Comment: is finding the intersection of two hyperplanes in $n$ dimension also NP-complete? According to https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f4a6/4713dbf19883878e1357a6dc2bdfc2a04f30.pdf

Comment: I’m not sure what that means. In any case, it sounds like a separate question.

Comment: Thank you. If this specific BLP is not P, then finding the intersection of two hyperplanes in $n$ dimension should also be NP-complete... because each row in the constraint condition can be regarded as a hyperplane, and the solution is just just equivalent to finding the intersection. However, intuitively, it shouldn't be that hard@_@