# Convex quadratic approximation to binary linear programming

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, integer-programming

Munapo (2016, American Journal of Operations Research, http://dx.doi.org/10.4236/ajor.2016.61001) purports to have a proof that binary linear programming [1] is solvable in polynomial time, and hence that P=NP.

Unsurprisingly, it does not really show this.

Its results are based on a convex quadratic approximation to the problem with a penalty term whose weight $\mathcal{l}$ needs to be infinitely large for the approximation to recover the true problem.

My questions are the following:

1. Is this an approximation which already existed in the literature (I rather expect it did)?
2. Is this approximation useful in practice? For example, could one solve a mixed integer linear programming problem by homotopy continuation [2], gradually increasing the weight $\mathcal{l}$?

---

Note: After writing this question I discovered this related question: [Time Complexity of Binary Linear Programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111561/time-complexity-of-binary-linear-programming) . The related question considers a specific binary linear programming problem, but mentions the paper above.

---

[1] Binary linear programming is linear programming subject to the constraint that certain variables can only take the values $0$ and $1$. Integer linear programming can be reduced to binary linear programming by introducing an additional variable for each element of the binary expansion of each variable.

[2] Homotopy continuation methods aim to track the solution of a problem as a parameter is allowed to smoothly vary. In practice, this usually means slightly increasing the parameter, and re-solving the problem, using the previous solution as initial condition. If there solution algorithm fails, then you reduce the step-size. If it passes, you can increase the step-size. There are also homotopy methods that map into differential equations, but those are less relevant here.